# Misunderstanding title in meta-tags gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags

I can't figure out why are my title meta_tags not being placed in the DOM.

I've read the documentation on meta_tags gem, but still can't figure it out.

In my application.html.erb, I have:

```
<%= display_meta_tags :site => 'Mysite' %>
```

(BTW, I still don't understand why do I need the `:site` there.

Then, in my view, I have:

```
<% title "Profile test" %>
<% description "This is a profile test" %>
<% keywords "profile,test" %>
```

Description and keywords are being rendered, but title wont.
It will render the `:site` value I put on application.html.erb, instead of the title meta_tag in the views.

Any ideas?

Thanks